# Format a date in VBscript to alphanumeric

Tags: vbscript, date-format

Is there a way to format a date in vbscript to this: 30-Nov-2013 or even 30-November-2013?
I've googled all day and i'm still coming up with nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
document.write("The current system date is: ")
document.write(DatePart("d", Date) & "-" & MonthName(DatePart("m", Date)) & "-" & DatePart("yyyy", Date) )
document.write(DatePart("d", Date) & "-" & MonthName(DatePart("m", Date), 1) & "-" & DatePart("yyyy", Date) )
```

Use [DatePart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4kt42529%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) to get day, month and year from a date.
Use [MonthName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58f13257%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) to get month name.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to using `DatePart` would be the `Day`, `Month` and `Year` functions:

```
Day(Date) & "-" & MonthName(Month(Date)) & "-" & Year(Date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or using `FormatDateTime` with `vbLongDate` (=1).

```
d = Split(FormatDateTime(Now, 1))
ReDim Preserve d(2)
d = Join(d, "-")
WScript.Echo d
```